# Is this UML association matching the code correctly?

Tags: java, uml, associations, diagram, class-diagram

[image: Uml-association]

I am trying to learn UML diagrams and I find it hard to understand this part. I have searched for a good explanation but coulnd't find one. 
I know that a `ProgramCordinator` should have a list with `Teacher`s.
But should the `Teacher` have a `ProgramCoordinator` even if the arrow sign is is like this `->` and not just a solid line?
Is there any difference between a solid line (-) and this (->)?

Here is my code :

```
public class ProgramCordinator{
   private List<Teacher> teachers;

   public ProgramCordinator(Teacher t){
      this.teachers.add(t);
   }

   public ProgramCordinator(){}

}

public class Teacher{
  private ProgramCordinator cordinator;

}
```

Can I instantiate a `ProgramCoordinator` without passing any arguments (although the diagram says that I should have at least one teacher in my list)? What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

An arrow on an association means navigability. The object at the arrow end can be seen by the object at the other side. It's so to say deprecated. Instead you note an owned property by using a large dot and the role name. See below.

Assuming that code was done after UML:

- *should the teacher have a program coordinator*?:
  No. It's just that there can only be one coordinator per teacher. The direction tells that there shall not be a way back. However, from a busniness perspective, the navigation does not make sense. Probably you agree that the teacher must know his coordinator since they have to talk to each other. The coder sensed that and made a better implementation than the UML told.
- *Can i instantiate a program coordinator without passing any arguments*?:
  I'm no Java coder but per your code you have an instantion alternative: with and without a teacher as parameter. The UML does not specify any instantiation operations. So both operations are a (needed) invention of the coder.

If the UML was made after the code:

- The navigation arrow is wrong
- The object creation operations are missing

Now (without showing 2nd flaw) the UML should be

[image]

A coordination can have no to endless teachers assigned. There's exactly one coordinator per teacher.

Of course there could be a reason for the UML design you show above. But honestly I could not imagine any ;-) So I go for a lack of UML knowledge.